# jQuery UI tooltip, can I copy text from it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In my current project I am using the tooltip of jQuery UI for show additional information. In this project, I have some tables where the text of some column doesn't fit, so part of them are hidden. I was thinking on use something like jQuery tooltip so when the user put the mouse over the cut cell, the tooltip show the complete text. The problem is that the user wouldn't be able to select the text.

Somebody knows if it possible configure jQuery UI tooltip for make possible copy/cut text or any other plugin that could be useful for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I did this:

CSS

```
.overflow_hidden_cell{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.overflow_hidden_cell_hover{
    overflow: visible;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);

}
```

JS

```
function setOverflowCells(){
    $('.overflow_hidden_cell').bind('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).addClass('overflow_hidden_cell_hover');
    }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('overflow_hidden_cell_hover');
    });
}
```

And I give the class '.overflow_hidden_cell' to every cell that could have a text too long. I hope this help anyone with the same problem.

Comment: thanks that's a very nice solution. exactly what I was looking for.
Just a little improvement:
You don't need any js for that. Just use the `:hover` attribute in css .

Comment: width did not work for me for some reason, but max-width did.
I also added to the hover rule: background-color:white !important
and to overflow_hidden_cell rule: text-overflow:ellipsis

Comment: can you please add the html table to the solution

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy tooltips, but you do have other options.  If you add an "onclick" or "onmouseover" to the shortened text, you can add copy that to the clipboard with a jquery plugin.  http://bradleysepos.com/projects/jquery/clipboard/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the jquery ui tooltip, with a little tweaking.  The following answer to a different question happens to solve this problem (works for me):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15014759/867704

Alternatively, the "Jquery Tools" tooltip is a plugin that provides a tooltip whose text can be copied by default:

http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/

Comment: I think the second link should be updated to http://jquerytools.github.io/download/