# jquery ui display tooltip when hovering over the tool tip

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a web page using jquery and jquery ui, and was wondering how to display the toolip when hovering over the tooltip itself, not just hovering over the element.  This is what I have so far...

Thanks in advance,

Scott Makos

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style2.css'>
        <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>
     <a id='id' href="" title="tooltip2">Desktops</a>
<script>
            $(function () {
            $("#id").tooltip({
            content: "<br><a href=\"item1\">Item1</a><br><a href=\"item2\">Item2</a><br><a href=\"item3\">Item3</a><br>",
                    show: null,
                    position: {
                        my: "left top",
                        at: "left bottom"
                    },
                    track: false                    
            });
        });
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This has a simple fix. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286514/jquery-ui-tooltip-set-timeout-and-set-hover-events-freeze-tooltip-on-mouseover/15014759#15014759 and here it is added to your code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JENaOJ

Comment: Great answer, thanks!!!